# How to include js file with no error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I want to separate my route file in nodejs. I use restify framework and this is part of my code:

```
app.routes((app)=>{
  require(__dirname + '/../routes/web.js')
})
```

routes/web.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("object");
})
```

When run the program I get this error:

> app is not a defined

How can I fix that?

In web.js `app` is `undefined` while I sended it to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main file

```
require(__dirname + '/../routes/web.js')(app)
```

routes/web.js:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.send("object");
    });
};
```